# Probability setting up recursion

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

Let $S = \left\{0,1\right\}$.

- Two players, say $A$ and $B$ alternate making random draws from $S$ with replacement.
- A player wins when they draw two consecutive zeros. Assume player $A$ draws first.

Compute the Probability player $A$ wins.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your efforts when asking a question. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/595055).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider state space $S=\{1,2\}\times \{1,2\}$, where $(a,b)\in S$ means that $A$ needs $a$ more zeros and $B$ needs $b$ more zeros.  Let $p(a,b)$ be the probability that $A$ wins, starting from state $(a,b)$, given that it is $A$'s turn.  We want to compute $p(2,2)$.  By conditioning on whether the next draw is $0$ or $1$, we find that
\begin{align}
p(1,1) &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} (1 - p(1,2)) \\
p(1,2) &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} (1 - p(2,2)) \\
p(2,1) &= \frac{1}{2} (1 - p(1,1)) + \frac{1}{2} (1 - p(1,2)) \\
p(2,2) &= \frac{1}{2} (1 - p(2,1)) + \frac{1}{2} (1 - p(2,2))
\end{align}
Now solve these four equations.